Which terminals support line numbers?
They can be useful when doing a lot of scrolling back and forth between command outputs.

IIUC, the bash history command and the various history movement operations, such as arrow up, arrow down, control-r to search for command with a string, are not what you need? Note that history commands are numbered, and have timestamps.

I don't use bash. I use primarily PowerShell, at least on Windows 11 and Fedora 40. Additionally, when switching between shells (for example, to python3, or even to sh to test POSIX commands) the history doesn't reflect that. I need a higher level of abstraction, and the terminal emulator seems to fit that.

As this Discourse post explains, KDE's Konsole provides this for Linux-based OSes:

Explanation
It can be enabled as this Bugzilla comment explains:

It is undocumented (and undiscoverable), but press Control + Alt + Reverse Solidus a couple of times.

That explains how to disable it too, but the mysterious "Sometimes" mode is explained at this Bugzilla comment as:

Control + Alt + Reverse Solidus cycles between three modes - always on, always off, and a third mode which shows only when a special combination of modifiers (configurable in edit profile - advanced) is pressed.

Examples

Always




Sometimes




Never






Also noteworthy is that a feature request exists for Visual Studio Code's terminal at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211249#issue-2261216495, which shall be able to be used independently when https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34442#issue-257984495 is completed.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community, you'll need to substantiate that. I can't act upon such vague advice.
